# Error: depends on dependency_overrides from unknown source, version solving failed

Tags: flutter, dart, yaml, dart-pub

When I try to override a dependency like this:

```
dependency_overrides:
  video_player:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/sanekyy/plugins.git
      ref: caching
      path: packages/video_player/video_player
```

I get this error

> Because my_flutter_project depends on dependency_overrides from unknown source "video_player", version solving failed.
> pub get failed (1; Because my_flutter_project depends on dependency_overrides from unknown source "video_player", version solving failed.)
> exit code 1

Any Ideas how I can override the video_player dependency such that I can use the video_player override from GitHub with other packages that use the usual video player?

Comment: have you finally solved your error?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with `dependency_overrides`, so I just replaced `third_lib: ^4.0.1` with `third_lib: path: home/delgan/packages/third_lib` (in the `dependencies` list) and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was just an indentation issue.
I had indented "dependency_overrides", like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  better_player: ^0.0.83
  dependency_overrides: # Note the indentation here.
    better_player:
      path: external-projects/betterplayer
```

While it should be:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  better_player: ^0.0.83
dependency_overrides: # Note the indentation here.
  better_player:
    path: external-projects/betterplayer
```